# passing local and instance variable with same name in java

Tags: java

If we pass local variable as argument to a print()within the same scope of a local variable method and instance variable also having same name as local variable name now the print() method print the variable name which value it ill print

Comment: Pretty easy to check it. Did you try to?

Comment: int a=5;arr(){int a=6; print(a);}print(a){s.o.p(a);}

Answer (score 2):

The local variable *shadows* an instance variable with the same name. If you want to access the instance variable, you have to use `this.myVar`.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable is printed as the output.

```
public class aaa {
    int i=1;  // instance variable
    /*
    To print this you have to write in the main() as
    aaa a = new aaa();
    System.out.println(a.i);
   */
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        int i=0; // local variable
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Because to access an instance variable you have to make an object. Then only you can print it.